# Describing the Minimum of a Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, extreme-value-analysis

I'm working on characteristic functions of GBM and implementing them in option pricing in python. In deriving the cf for the minimum of a drifted BM I make this step:

> First, note that by implementing the definition of a minimum, also using the symmetry property of Brownian Motion, we can rewrite $\widetilde N_0^T$ as follows
> $$\begin{equation}
>      \widetilde N_0^T = -\max_{0 \leq t \leq T}\big(-\widetilde W(t)\big) 
>      = -\max_{0 \leq t \leq T}\big(-W(t) -\alpha t\big) 
>      = -\max_{0 \leq t \leq T}\big(W(t) -\alpha t\big)
> \end{equation}$$

Is this expression for the minimum faulty? I have been sifting through the code implementation for errors elsewhere for hours now, so is this the problem? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The step $-\max(-W(t)-\alpha t) = -\max(W(t)-\alpha t)$ is not correct.  This is true *in distribution* when $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion.  If you are operating in a measure under which $W(t)$ is not a Brownian motion, or need to worry about the joint distribution of $\tilde N$ and any other random variable that is not independent of $W$, then this step may cause some problems.